# How do I define a class template with specfic format of taking template arguments? e.g.: Fn(Args...)

Tags: c++, class, templates

```cpp
template<class Fn, class ...Args>
class func_class<Fn(Args...)> // Do not know what to do here
{
        typedef typename result_of<Fn(Args...)>::type mytype;
        std::function<mytype(Args...)> func_;
        std::tuple<Args...> tuple1;
    public:
        func_class(Fn&& func_in, Args&& ...args) 
        {
            func_ = func_in;
            tuple1 = make_tuple(args...);
        }
    
        mytype
        exe () 
        {
            mytype ret;
            ret = apply(func_, tuple1);
            return ret;
        }
};

int func(int a) {return a;}

int main () {
   // return type of "func" can be deduced by "result_of<decltype(func)&(int)>::type"
   // And result_of is declared as "result_of<Fn(Args...)>"
   // Want func_class to have the same interface
   func_class<decltype(func)&(int)> fc; // Want to declare a object like this 
   fc.exe();
}
```

The code is like above. Return type of `func` can be deduced by `result_of<decltype(func)&(int)>::type`. And `result_of` is declared as `result_of<Fn(Args...)>`.
Want `func_class` to have the same interface as `result_of`.
The compiler complains like:

```
test.cpp:211:7: error: 'func_class' is not a class template
```

What can I do?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class Sig>
struct bob;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct bob<R(Args...)>{
  //...
};
```

specialization.

Uses of `bob` that fail to pattern match will give compile-time errors.

As a note, using `R(Args...)` syntax when `R` is **not** a return value and `Args...` are **not** arguments will lead to unexpected quirks, because of how function argument and return value types are modified by the C/C++ language.

This is why `std::result_of<F(Args...)>` is deprecated and replaced with `std::invoke_result<F, Args...>`.

`R(Args...)` is appropriately used in `std::function`, because `Args...` are function arguments, and `R` is an actual return value, to `function<A(Args...)>::operator()`.